# (node:9555) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'lineno' of module exports inside circular dependency. ERROR: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

My Angular 10.x app builds and runs fine under Node 10.14.1
I'm trying to build it under Node 14.15.0 and I'm getting the following errors:

```
Building Angular Package
(node:9555) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'lineno' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:9555) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'column' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:9555) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'filename' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:9555) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'lineno' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:9555) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'column' of module exports inside circular dependency
(node:9555) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'filename' of module exports inside circular dependency
```

And then it ends with this:

```
Compiling TypeScript sources through ngc
ERROR: Maximum call stack size exceeded
An unhandled exception occurred: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I've tried adding `--trace-warnings` to my build command from command line:

Terminal: `npm run rebuild-projects --verbose --trace-warnings`

However, the `(Use node --trace-warnings ...)` note still shows up in the output like the flag was not recognized in my build command.

I'm just trying to start there in order to try to determine what is causing the error for me. For what its worth, I'm on a Mac. I have a colleague on a Windows PC that can build this same project fine under Node 14.15.0

Answer (score 0):

Update the Angular CLI :

```
ng update @angular/cli
```

Update the Angular core package  :

```
ng update @angular/core
```

Comment: This project is a library that is used in an app that is bound to Angular 10.2.x. I don't want to update the project to a different angular version. I just want to make it so that it runs under a higher version of Node.

Comment: try to add --preserve-symlinks when building

Comment: or you can try increasing the maximum call stack size in Node by adding the --stack-size=<number> to your build command

Comment: Thanks for your help! It was ng-packagr needed a slight update.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my issue by updating ng-packagr from version 10 to 11:

Updated `"ng-packagr": "^10.0.0",` to `"ng-packagr": "^11.0.2",`

No more call stack errors

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.4",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.1000.4",
    "@angular/cli": "10.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "10.0.4",
    "ng-packagr": "^11.0.2",
    ...
}
```

This app is stuck on Angular 10.x for the moment due to the fact its a library that's consumed by apps that are still on Angular 10.x